# I want a hyperlink to open a browser tab, then all subsequent link clicks go to the same tab

Tags: google-chrome, html, hyperlink, browser-tabs, tabbed-browsing

I suspect I'm out of luck on this one, but here goes...

Say I have a CHM help file that has http:// hyperlinks embedded in the help pages.  When the user clicks on a hyperlink of the style:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">click here!</a>
```

a browser window is opened and the target web page is displayed.  If a browser is already open a new tab is created and the target displayed in that.  If the user clicks on another link (or the same link) *another* browser window/tab opens, and so on.

Is there any way I can force all clicks of the links to go to the same tab/browser window?

Comment: No. least, not with anything I am aware of.

Comment: Have you tried a different `target` name? I'm not on a Windows right now (and know nothing about CHM files), but `target="foo"` in a browser opens a new tab/window the first time, and opens subsequent links in that same window, as it implicitly receives that target name. `_blank` is a special value that means "always open in new window".

Comment: I tested it in a simple html page, and it works! So I assume it would in a CHM file.

Comment: I just tested it with Chrome - still opens each click in a new tab.

Comment: @soandos, @Peter - is this a browser-specific thing then?

Answer (score 5):

Change the value of the "target" parameter to something other than "_blank" (which is reserved by the standards for always opening a new page without a name).

The "target" parameter allows you to specify a name (I recommend using a name that does NOT begin with an underscore) to open the new window in.  By using the same name in other Anchor REFerences (hyper-text links), that new window that was opened previously will simply be re-used (instead of opening a new window again).

Comment: Thanks @Randolf.  It seems to work on IE8 but Chrome opens a new tab each time.

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support this?  It's a **standard feature that all web browsers are supposed to support**.  Either there's something wrong with IE8 on your computer (most likely, and SpyWare is a logical culprit), or Microsoft has decided that the standards aren't important and decided not to implement this feature (this would cause a lot of problems, so I suspect that they wouldn't dare do this).

Comment: Hi @Randolf.  No, IE _does_ support it.  Chrome doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
target="_blank"
```

use

```
target="__blank"
```

Comment: While this may provide a solution, it would be good to mention *why* they should use one over the other.